# Pass touch events to underlying view when click on transparent area, but allow clicks on buttons

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a problem because I don't know how to make the transparent background of Fragment B pass on touch events to Fragment A:

[image: diagram]

Fragment C has Fragment B layered on top of Fragment A: **Fragment C XML:**

```
...
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_A_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_B_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
 ...
```

And here is where Fragment C attaches the fragments to those FrameLayouts: **Fragment C class:**

```
...
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_A_container, FragmentA, TAG_FRAGMENT_A);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_B_container, FragmentB, TAG_FRAGMENT_B);
...
```

But now, I don't know how to only let the toolbar and floating action button get clicked, but the rest of the background pass on the click event to Fragment A? Here is a basic idea of Fragment B's layout: **FragmentB XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually did work, but I noticed that in my code, it was really doing this (`FragmentD` is an opaque background meant to go underneath `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`):

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_A_container, FragmentD, TAG_FRAGMENT_D);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_A_container, FragmentA, TAG_FRAGMENT_A);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_B_container, FragmentB, TAG_FRAGMENT_B);
```

I would think that by adding `FragmentD` and *then* adding `FragmentA` to `fragment_A_container`, `FragmentA` should be on top of `FragmentD`, but I guess it wasn't the case. So I guaranteed that the order would be correct by separating them into their own FrameLayouts, and it worked fine:

Updated XML:

```
...
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_D_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_A_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_B_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
 ...
```